# How do I find out what escape sequence my terminal needs to send?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, tmux, byobu

I am using the terminal application on osX to connect to ubuntu (12.04 i think). I have the terminal at it's default setting of xerm-256. In this mode the terminal sends the sequence of \033OQ when F2 is pressed. There is no mapping however for Shift-F2 or Control-F2. There is also no sequences set for Shift-Left, Shift-Right, Control-Left, Control-Right, etc. I need some of these keys to operate features from time to time in various programs. Take for example byobu. Shift-F2 and Control-F2 are used to split the screen vertically and horizontally. In tmux the arrow keys are used with shift and control for resizing panes.

My problem is that I don't know what sequence the terminal should send. How do I find out what these sequences should be? I know that I can press Control-v and then a key to get the code that is being received but this is not what I need. I don't need to see what sequence is being sent. I need to know what sequence I need to send.

For instance my left arrow sends ^[OD. My Control-Left sends ^[[5D]. However my up and down keys have no distinction. My down sends ^[OB and Control-down also sends ^[OB. Same problem with my up key. It is the same with or without shift.

Is there a list somewhere with all of the keys and there codes, specifically with modifiers such as shift, control, alt/option?

How can I find out what the expected sequence is so I can send what is needed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### XTerm

Since you are advertising that you are using an *xterm* (via your TERM value), you will most likely want to arrange to send the sequences that *xterm* would send for these keys. The [ctlseqs](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) documentation from *xterm* describes these particular modified key sequences at the bottom of the [PC-Style Function Keys](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#PC-Style%20Function%20Keys) section:

> … xterm recognizes function key modifiers which are parameters appended before the final character of the control sequence.
>
> ```
>     2 Shift
>     3 Alt
>     4 Shift + Alt
>     5 Control
>     6 Control + Shift
>     ⋮
> ```

### Examples

<kbd>F5</kbd> sends `^[[15~`, so <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> should send `^[[15;2~` (i.e. add `;2` before the final character)

The arrow keys and the first four function keys are a bit different. They often use SS3-based sequences (starting with `^[O`); these will need to be changed to CSI-based equivalents (starting with `^[[`) since SS3 sequences can not have parameters. Also, the normal sequences for the keys do not usually have a numeric parameter, so a placeholder(?) `1` parameter is also added:

<kbd>Up</kbd> sends `^[[A` or `^[OA`, so <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> should send `^[[1;2A` (i.e. switch to CSI, and add `1;2` before the final character)

<kbd>F1</kbd> sends `^[OP`, so <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> should send `^[[1;2P` (i.e. switch to CSI, add `1;2` before the final character)

You might also like to look at the source code of various terminal emulators to see whay they do. For example, the relevant bits of *tmux* are in its [`xterm-keys.c` file](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/xterm-keys.c).

### Configuration

Since your terminal emulator is not already sending all the sequences you want to support, you will have to configure it to do so. The built-in terminal emulator that comes with OS X, *Terminal*, has a few keys preconfigured, but you will probably have to add most of them yourself. You can get to the list of keys by invoking the **Terminal** > **Preferences…** menu item, selecting the top-level **Settings** tab, picking the appropriate profile, and switching to its **Keyboard** tab. From there you can add and remove key definitions. For example, you could define `F2` with `shift` to `send string to shell:` (sic) and type <kbd>ESC</kbd> followed by `[1;2Q` into the string text box (the <kbd>ESC</kbd> will show up as `\033`, this is okay).

Note: Changing the definition of <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> might affect how some programs (e.g. shells and Emacs) work with those keystrokes. The default configuration sends ESC-f and ESC-b, which are Emacs-style keystrokes for backward-word and forward-word that many programs will understand by default. This configuration seems backwards to me; the shell (and other programs) should be configured to recognize proper modified arrow key sequences instead.

You might also want to try a different terminal emulator. [*iTerm* 2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) has built-in support for most of these modified keys (maybe not the Control+Fn variants), so there would be less to manually configure.

Also, note that OS X has some system-wide shortcuts defined for some of the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Fx</kbd> combinations (see *System Preferences*, **Keyboard**, **Keyboard Shortcuts**, **Keyboard & Text Input**). You will have to disable some of these shortcuts to make sure that *Terminal* or *iTerm* has a chance to “see” your desired key combinations.

Comment: Wow! That was exactly what I needed. I had been to the xterm documentation but it did not make sense to me until you explained it.

Comment: `xterm-keys.c` is gone. instead, see [tty-keys.c](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/tty-keys.c)